# How to configure regex for Track lack of copyright and license headers

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am getting error "Add or update the header of this file.". I have set isRegularExpression=true with regex header format.

HeaderFormat

```
^[a-z,A-Z, ,#,0-9]*
\/\*\s*
\s*\* SampleSonarQube\s*
\s*\* Copyright \(c\) [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} XYZ corporation\s*
\s*\* ProjectName:[a-z,A-Z,.]*\s*
\s*\* [a-z,A-Z,.]*\s*
\s*\* Created On: [0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-9]{4}\s*
\*\/\s*
[a-z,A-Z, ,#,0-9]*$
```

Sample Header

```
#region copyright
/*
 * SampleSonarQube
 * Copyright (c) 2017-2018 XYZ corporation
 * ProjectName:MyProject
 * Testclass.cs
 * Created On: 8-11-2018
*/
#endregion

using ....
```

Can anyone please help me in identifying the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing whitespace pattern at the end of first line.

Please try with this regex pattern.

^[a-z,A-Z, ,#,0-9]*\s*/*\s*\s** SampleSonarQube\s*\s** Copyright (c) [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4} XYZ corporation\s*\s** ProjectName:[a-z,A-Z,.]*\s*\s** [a-z,A-Z,.]*\s*\s** Created On: [0-3]?[0-9]-[0-3]?[0-9]-[0-9]{4}\s**/\s*[a-z,A-Z, #,0-9]*$